Setting Recursion Limit in LangGraph's StateGraph with Pregel Engine
I have built a stateGraph for agents powered by LLMs on python.
class GraphState:

    def __init__(self):
    self.article = ""
    self.feedback = ""
    self.score = 0
    self.iteration_count = 0
    self.topic = ""
workflow=StateGraph(GraphState)

I got an error:

GraphRecursionError: Recursion limit of 25 reachedwithout hitting a stop condition. You can increase the limit by setting the recursion_limit config key.

I wanted to set the recursion_limit to 5. I tried the following:
    workflow=StateGraph(GraphState)
    workflow.set_config({'recursion_limit': 3})*

I got an error

AttributeError: 'StateGraph' object has no attribute 'set_config'

I then tried this:
  from langgraph.pregel import Pregel
  engine = Pregel(config={'recursion_limit': 3})
  workflow = StateGraph(GraphState, engine=engine)

I get this error:

ValidationError: 1 validation error for Pregel
nodes
field required (type=value_error.missing)


Try setting it on iterating over stream. Like for example
for s in app.stream(inputs, {"recursion_limit": 10}):
    print(list(s.values())[0])
    print("----")


You have to set it using RunnableConfig instead of just a dictionary:

Just import: from langchain_core.runnables import RunnableConfig
Then use it like this:
def invoke(self, input_query):
    inputs = {"question": input_query}
    result = None
    config = RunnableConfig(recursion_limit=15)
    try:
        for output in self.app.stream(inputs, config):
            for key, value in output.items():
                logging.info(f"Node '{key}':")
                result = value
    except GraphRecursionError:
        result = None
        logging.error("Graph recursion limit reached.")

    return result




Try this and see if it helps.
app = workflow.compile()
app.stream(inputs, {"recursion_limit": 10})

or 
app.invoke(inputs, {"recursion_limit": 100})


The RunnableConfig class in Langchain allows you to configure the maximum recursion depth using the recursion_limit argument. By default, this limit is set to 25, but you can increase or decrease it to control how many times a function can call itself within a chain.
from langchain_core.runnables.config import RunnableConfig
config = RunnableConfig(recursion_limit=10)
print(config)
// {'recursion_limit': 10}

# Define a new graph
workflow = StateGraph(AgentState)
app = workflow.compile()
app.invoke(inputs, config)

